# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle without 'android:exported' property set in xamarin forms Android application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.xam.mobileapp" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.7" android:versionCode="30">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="Pragyan" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:allowBackup="false">
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="true"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true"  android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
        <!--<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyAU3On6yQ8TZWJSce62TjXcXTWCm7MoXIU" />-->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" tools:node="merge" android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msal{appid}" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Even after adding the property **android:exported="true"** at required places receving the same error msg.
Any one facing same issue in xamarin forms (Android application).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you miss something(receiver, provider, service or activity) and forget to register in the Android Manifest file? By the way, the problem of this [case(without 'android:exported' property set)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815448/you-uploaded-an-apk-or-android-app-bundle-without-androidexported-property-se) is similar to yours, it could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that if you have any service created in your android solution, add tag there.
- Replace  [Service] with  [Service(Exported = false)]
- Please update Google play packages and Firebase Packages in your solution with latest versions to resolve the issue.

And you are good to go.!

Answer (score 0):

Did check the generated androidmanifest.xml in the obj folder, that is the one that counts?